# Prevent bs4 from truncating html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

`beautifulsoup4` happen to truncate invalid (I guess) html in some instances. I would love to force it not to do that. I am assuming there in no 'formal' way, but perhaps you have accomplished that before somehow?

Comment: Please give an example of the HTML input, the output you're seeing, the code you're using, the version of bs4 you're using, and which parser (and parser version, and, if it's lxml, which libxml2 version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML is broken, reconstructing a workable element tree is not always possible. However, you can try using different backend parsers. Not all parsers can treat broken HTML the same.

The `html5lib` parser is especially adept at dealing with broken HTML, handling such input the same as most browsers would:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, 'html5')
```

You can also try `lxml` here. Both libraries are separate installs.

Comment: Thank you. Performance isnt a concern here just curious, is `html5` that slow or it's just me?

Comment: `html5lib` is indeed slower, it does a lot more work.